# How can I make my ubuntu WiFi on startup default off?

Tags: wireless, 15.04, startup, wicd

Please show how to keep WiFi off on boot up. Wicd automatically starts on boot up. Thanks.

```
Wicd Network Manager
3.19.0-25-generic GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the WIFI selection (icon looks like a fan - usually in the top right screen corner next to "En" for character map and keyboard layout, etc.), then EDIT CONNECTIONS and deselect "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" under the "General" tab for EVERY network connection shown.  Then disconnect from the network you are currently connected to and it should not reconnect automatically.  Whenever you reboot the PC it should not connect to a network automatically either.

Comment: Thanks, however, those options are not available.